# SUMPRODUCT with multiple conditions - EXCEL

Tags: microsoft-excel

In an Excel spreadsheet, I have dates in column B and email addresses in column K.

I need the number of unique emails that appear in column K for each date. Sometimes the email addresses appear multiple times.

Sample Data:

```
B1: 7/18/15, K1: someone1@emailhost.com 
B2: 7/18/15, K2: someone2@emailhost.com
B3: 7/18/15, K3: someone3@emailhost.com
B4: 7/18/15, K4: someone4@emailhost.com
B5: 7/18/15, K5: someone4@emailhost.com

B7: 7/19/15, K7: someone5@emailhost.com
B8: 7/19/15, K8: someone5@emailhost.com
B9: 7/19/15, K9: someone6@emailhost.com
B10: 7/19/15, K10: someone6@emailhost.com
B11: 7/19/15, K11: someone7@emailhost.com
```

Then, in columns P & Q, I want the date and number of unique emails in column K, totaled by each date, on its own blank line.

```
P6: 7/18/15
Q6: 4 (using this formula: =SUMPRODUCT((K1:K5<>"")/COUNTIF(K1:K5,K1:K5&""))

P12: 7/19/15
Q12: 3 (using this formula: =SUMPRODUCT((K7:K11<>"")/COUNTIF(K7:K11,K7:K11&""))
```

QUESTION:
How to create a formula with conditions, if the data is in column P and B, so I don't have to manually edit the Excel formula for each date range I put in my formulas in column Q.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an "array formula" in `Q6` copied down

`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(IF(B$1:B$1000=P6,IF(K$1:K$1000<>"",MATCH(K$1:K$1000,K$1:K$1000,0))),ROW(B$1:B$1000)-ROW(B$1)+1),1))`

confirm with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

That assumes you have up to `1000` rows of data, adjust formula if you have more but don't use whole columns